# A form for each WebGrid row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, razor

I have a WebGrid. Now, I would like to let the user edit a quantity in each Column row.

Sine I have little experience with jQuery and AJAX, I would like to do this with just HTML/C#. So I was thinking, the simplest way would be to have a form for each row.

The WebGrid may have hundreds, if not thousands of rows.

Is this common practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: How much experience do you have with C#?  Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think this is common practice. First of all, Thousands of rows on a webpage can consume some data making the webpage slow. especially if all this data is also saved in the view state. Trust me I tried and failed.

Second, you can simply add a textbox to a normal grid view with a button to update the row / or the entire grid. Make sure you have an ID hidden in the gridview.

You can than call a method referring to the ID like:    gridview.selectedindex[0]